# jQuery Autocomplete to find exact match

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I hav a jQuery Autocomplete for airports. My dataset contains label and value.
Sample:

```
var Airports = [
    { "label": "DMB - Dzhambyl, Dzhambyl Airport", "value": "DMB" }, 
    { "label": "EMA - Nottingham, Nottingham East Midlands Airport", "value": "EMA" }, 
    { "label": "HAM - Hamburg, Hamburg Airport", "value": "HAM" }    
];
```

When I enter HAM (which is the 3LC for Hamburg Airport) I currently get all of these three items as a result. But I only want to see "HAM - Hamburg, Hamburg Airport" if the value of this item matches the exact search request. It should also be possible to find all entries with e.g. "burg" in it if I would search for that.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/pguoa197/1/

Comment: In the jQuery Autocomplete API documentation http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ there is a sample showing how to match from the beginning of the text.

Comment: yeah, but both should be possible. If I use "search from beginning of text" than I will find HAM-Hamburg, but no entries with "burg" in the middle of the text if I would search for that

Comment: So you want to match on the value if it's an exact hit, otherwise match on the text? In that case, modify the source function to provide that behavior.

Comment: That's excactly what I want. But if I would know how to do that I would have done that :-(

Comment: I wouldn't even want to write it. I'd be tempted to push back on that being a requirement, as it seems of minimal value to me compared to the cost of maintaining that search function in the future.

Comment: You might be 100% right on that...... already spend a few hours on that. Thx anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know who voted this question down and why... but here is the solution for who ever will need something similar in the future:

```
$(function () {
    var Airports = [
        { "label": "DMB - Dzhambyl, Dzhambyl Airport", "value": "DMB" }, 
        { "label": "EMA - Nottingham, Nottingham East Midlands Airport", "value": "EMA" }, 
        { "label": "HAM - Hamburg, Hamburg Airport", "value": "HAM" }    
    ];


$("#depart").autocomplete({
     source: function (request, response) {
        var term = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term)
            , startsWithMatcher = new RegExp("^" + term, "i")
            , startsWith = $.grep(Airports, function(value) {
                return startsWithMatcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
            })
            , containsMatcher = new RegExp(term, "i")
            , contains = $.grep(Airports, function (value) {
                return $.inArray(value, startsWith) < 0 && 
                    containsMatcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
            });

            response(startsWith.concat(contains));
    },
    minLength: 3
  });
});
```

Working Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/pguoa197/5/

Comment: I don't see how this is a fix as it shows the exact same result as the code in the question. If all you wanted to do was move `HAM` up in the list, you can specify a custom sort.

Comment: It's not the same. When you enter HAM, Hamburg comes up first now (matching 3LC), then the rest. In the initial sample Hamburg was on pos 3 only

Comment: In which case you just needed to implements a custom sort. Your question implies that you wanted to filter on the first characters only - `But I only want to see "HAM - Hamburg, Hamburg Airport" if the value of this item matches the exact search request`

Answer (score 0):

From your problem description it sounds like you only want to match from the start of the value string. In which case you can create your own filter method for the auto complete, like this:

```
$.ui.autocomplete.filter = function (array, term) {
    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");
    return $.grep(array, function (value) {
        return matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
    });
};
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/pguoa197/3/)

Comment: Thx Rory, for Hamburg (ham) this works fine. But it should also be possible to find e.g. "Nottingham". That's no longer the case now

Comment: I'm afraid it's one or the other. `ham` is a valid part of both strings, so will be displayed when searched for.